# Godot 4.0 make unlit objects be transparent instead of black

Tags: mask, godot, light

How do I make objects that are not actively being lit by a light source be *transparent* as opposed to just black?

I'm trying to achieve an effect with a `PointLight2D` where selected layers inside the light's region of influence are lit while all other layers are transparent in that region. Outside this `PointLight2D`'s region, however, everything should stay unaffected by the light (as in they should behave as though that light was never there and stay the default "lit" look)

I've tried making this work using light masks and canvas layers. While I am able to select the objects I want using light masks, canvas layers don't work since objects higher up in the layer hierarchy will still occlude objects below and I don't want to make layers transparent or rearrange them.

How can I achieve this effect? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I'm looking to do something like a `light_only` render mode shader, however this feature appears to be broken in Godot 4 at the moment